# Bitbucket API receiving GET return when sending a POST request

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I am trying to create a new project using Bitbucket API to this endpoint: [http://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/{My_Workspace}/projects](http://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/%7BMy_Workspace%7D/projects)
by sending a POST request.

For headers I am passing:
Authorization: Bearer + access token,
Content-Type: application/json

For body I am passing:
{
"name": "test",
"key": "TEST",
"is_private": "true",
"scm": "git"
}

I return 200 but my return body is what you would expect to get if you were to send a GET request to get your existing projects.

How can I create a new project in Bitbucket using Bitbucket API?
In my request am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your code to make the POST?

Comment: @Randommm

headers = {
        Authorization: "Bearer %s" % access_token,
    };
    data = {
        name: projectName,
        key: projectKey.toUpperCase(),
        is_private: true,
        scm: "git",
    };
    try {
        await axios.post(
            "http://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/{my workspace}/projects",
            headers,
            JSON.stringify(data)
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }